# How to use nircmd.exe and set filename %~nF in batch for loop

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to write a batch file that iterates through each filename, takes part of the strings, and sets the created and modified dates.
Mind you, dirpath is a placeholder for actual path.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /R dirpath %F in (*.*) DO (SET FNAME=%~nF SET MM=%FNAME:~0,2% SET DD=%FNAME:~2,2% SET YY=%FNAME:~4,2% nircmd.exe setfiletime %F "%DD% %MM%-20%YY% 00:00:00" "%DD%-%MM%-20%YY% 00:00:00")
```

I'm not sure how to even troubleshoot what the script is doing - pause doesn't pause the program after the loop.
How can this be rewritten to function?

Comment: Please give us a clue. What doesn't work? Any error messages?

Comment: Start by commenting out the `@echo off`. Read [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: I really don't know how to answer that question, I don't know how to make the script pause rather than finish in a brief milisecond.

Comment: This is what the file gives (. and dirname replaces what actually is):
    .>REM @echo off 

    .>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
    F was unexpected at this time.

    .>FOR /R dirname F in (*.*) DO

Comment: Please don't change the question. You invalidate all the comments in my answer. Question rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can this be rewritten to function?

You have a number of problems with your batch file:

- It's not `%f`. You need use `%%f` instead. `%f` is for a command line, that needs fixing in at least 3 places.
- I would put the commands inside the `do ( ... )` on separate lines.
- You can put a pause before the closing `)`
- You can comment out the first line with `rem` to see what the batch file is doing.
- Add `echo` to the payload line with `nircmd`.
- Remove the `echo` when you think it's working.
- You need in some places to use `!` instead of `%` inside the `for`loop (that's what `enabledelayedexpansion` is for - it enables variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time

Start with the following batch file (I've fixed the main mistakes for you):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r dirpath %%F in (*.*) DO (
  set FNAME=%%~nF
  SET MM=!FNAME:~0,2!
  SET DD=!FNAME:~2,2!
  SET YY=!FNAME:~4,2!
  echo nircmd.exe setfiletime %%F "!DD!-!MM!-20!YY! 00:00:00" "!DD!-!MM!-20!YY! 00:00:00"
  pause
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) - Loop through files (Recurse subfolders).
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) - Set options to control the visibility of environment variables in a batch file.

Comment: It doesn't quite work - I think it is close.  FNAME is still not being set to the filename.

Comment: @alrightgame Answer updated. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution by simply calling a function.

```
FOR /R dirname %%F in (*.*) DO call :Setfiletime %%F
goto End
:Setfiletime
   SET FNAME=%~n1
   echo %FNAME%
   SET MM=%FNAME:~0,2%
   SET DD=%FNAME:~2,2%
   SET YY=%FNAME:~4,2%
   nircmd.exe setfiletime %1 "%DD%-%MM%-20%YY%" "%DD%-%MM%-20%YY%"
:goto :eof
:End
```

Thanks everyone for all your help.